# Amazon Glacier How to delete files after a certain period of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

Thanks for reading this.

I am able to transfer files from S3 to Glacier after 30 days using lifecycle rule. However, how do I make the same files get deleted from Glacier after 3 months?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the objects were moved from S3 to Glacier via a Lifecycle Policy, add a **permanently delete** setting to the lifecycle policy to Delete the objects after *n* days. This will delete the objects from both S3 and Glacier.

If, instead, the objects were uploaded directly to Glacier, then there is no auto-deletion capability.

Comment: I have created a s3 life cycle policy which will `Expire the current version of the object in 540 days`. 
I am a bit confused here, whether it deletes the objects from s3 or glacier,
if not I want to delete the objects from a bucket in 540 days and the glacier in some 4 years! how will I set it up?

Comment: @Rajatjain Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, Glacier does not currently have lifecycle policies for Glacier vaults like it does for S3.

You could create your own autodelete setup (likely within the [not-expiring-after-12-months AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=categories%23alwaysfree)) by writing metadata about the Glacier archives to DynamoDB (vault name, archive id, timestamp) and have a scheduled Lambda function that looks for archives older than 30 days and deletes them from Glacier and DynamoDB.

It's a bit of work to set up, but it would accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: The question refers to S3 objects transitioned to the glacier storage class.  These objects are still S3 objects, still subject to S3 lifecycle policies -- they aren't accessible via the Glacier API.

Comment: Ah that's true. In that case, the OP would just need to add a deletion lifecycle policy to the S3 bucket, as @JohnRotenstein mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @Tom very nice idea. Thanks. Any pointers how can I pipe the output from a glacier upload job to the DynamoDB? I am currently using AWS tools for Powershell to access glacier API. Ideally I would modify the JSON object from the Write-GlcArchive to include additional attributes before piping it to the DynamoDB API, all through a PS command